# Change jQuery slider to SVG Slider

Tags: d3.js

This is a follow-up question to [Put title above slider in D3 svg element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48445406/put-title-above-slider-in-d3-svg-element). I've decided that the best option is to use a SVG slider and put the title on top of it.

Here is my current implementation, using a jQuery slider (note that the title and slider need their places switched):

```js
var dataAsCsv = `date,col_1,col_2
11/1/2012,1977652,1802851
12/1/2012,1128739,948687
1/1/2013,1201944,1514667
2/1/2013,1863148,1834006
3/1/2013,1314851,1906060
4/1/2013,1283943,1978702
5/1/2013,1127964,1195606
6/1/2013,1773254,977214
7/1/2013,1929574,1127450
8/1/2013,1980411,1808161
9/1/2013,1405691,1182788
10/1/2013,1336790,937890
11/1/2013,1851053,1358400
12/1/2013,1472623,1214610
1/1/2014,1155116,1757052
2/1/2014,1571611,1935038
3/1/2014,1898348,1320348
4/1/2014,1444838,1934789
5/1/2014,1235087,950194
6/1/2014,1272040,1580656
7/1/2014,980781,1680164
8/1/2014,1391291,1115999
9/1/2014,1211125,1542148
10/1/2014,1020824,1782795
11/1/2014,1685081,926612
12/1/2014,1469254,1767071
1/1/2015,1168523,935897
2/1/2015,1602610,1450541
3/1/2015,1830278,1354876
4/1/2015,1275158,1412555
5/1/2015,1560961,1839718
6/1/2015,949948,1587130
7/1/2015,1413765,1494446
8/1/2015,1166141,1305105
9/1/2015,958975,1202219
10/1/2015,902696,1023987
11/1/2015,961441,1865628
12/1/2015,1363145,1954046
1/1/2016,1862878,1470741
2/1/2016,1723891,1042760
3/1/2016,1906747,1169012
4/1/2016,1963364,1927063
5/1/2016,1899735,1936915
6/1/2016,1300369,1430697
7/1/2016,1777108,1401210
8/1/2016,1597045,1566763
9/1/2016,1558287,1140057
10/1/2016,1965665,1953595
11/1/2016,1800438,937551
12/1/2016,1689152,1221895
1/1/2017,1607824,1963282
2/1/2017,1878431,1415658
3/1/2017,1730296,1947106
4/1/2017,1956756,1696780
5/1/2017,1746673,1662892
6/1/2017,989702,1537646
7/1/2017,1098812,1592064
8/1/2017,1861973,1892987
9/1/2017,1129596,1406514
10/1/2017,1528632,1725020
11/1/2017,925850,1795575`;



var margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 80
  },
  width = 1400 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);


var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// parse the date / time
// look at the .csv in Notepad! DO NOT LOOK AT EXCEL!
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");

var sessions_desktop_col = "#CE1126",
  sessions_mobile_col = "#00B6D0";

var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range([sessions_desktop_col, sessions_mobile_col]); // red and blue 

var xMonthAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
  .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b")); // label every month

var xYearAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
  .ticks(d3.timeYear.every(1))
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y")); // label every year

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(d3.format('.2s')).tickSize(-width + margin.left + margin.right);

var formatNum = d3.format(",");

var barPad = 8;

var data = d3.csvParse(dataAsCsv, function(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
});

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
});

var keys = data.columns.slice(1);

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.date - a.date;
});


x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.date
}));

var max = x.domain()[1];
var min = x.domain()[0];

var datePlusOneMonth = d3.timeDay.offset(d3.timeMonth.offset(max, 1), -1); // last day of current month: move up one month, back one day 

x.domain([min, datePlusOneMonth]);

y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.total;
})]).nice();
z.domain(keys);

// x-axis
var monthAxis = g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xMonthAxis);

var defaultSliderValue = 25;

// calculate offset date based on initial slider value
var offsetDate = defaultSliderValue ? d3.timeDay.offset(d3.timeMonth.offset((new Date(datePlusOneMonth.getFullYear(), datePlusOneMonth.getMonth() - defaultSliderValue)), 1), -1) : min
// set x domain and re-render xAxis
x.domain([offsetDate, datePlusOneMonth]);
g.select('.x.axis').call(xMonthAxis);

var filteredData = data.filter(function(d) {
  return d.date >= offsetDate;
});
barWidth = (width - margin.right - margin.left) / (filteredData.length + barPad);

// the bars 
g.append("g").classed('bars', true)
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(filteredData))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr('class', function(d) {
    return d.key;
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return z(d.key);
  })
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.data.date);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("width", barWidth)
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {

    //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
    var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.mouse(this)[0]) + 88;
    var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.mouse(this)[1]) + 50;
    var value = d.data[d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('class')]; // differentiating between col1 and col2 values
    var totalCount = d.data["total"];
    var valuePercent = value / totalCount;
    var valueClass = d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('class').replace("col_1", "Column 1").replace("col_2", "Column 2");

    //Update the tooltip position and value
    d3.select("#tooltip")
      .style("left", xPosition + "px")
      .style("top", yPosition + "px")

    d3.select("#tooltip")
      .select("#count")
      .text(formatNum(value)); // return the value 

    d3.select("#tooltip")
      .select("#totalCount")
      .text(formatNum(totalCount)); // return the value 

    d3.select("#tooltip")
      .select("#percent")
      .text((valuePercent * 100).toFixed(1) + "%"); // return the value 

    d3.select("#tooltip")
      .select("#month")
      .text(d3.timeFormat("%B %Y")(d.data.date)); // return the value 

    d3.select("#tooltip")
      .select("#sessionLabel")
      .text(valueClass); // return the class 

    //Show the tooltip
    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);

  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    //Hide the tooltip
    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);

  });

g.selectAll("bars")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,300)");

const firstDataYear = x.domain()[0];
if (firstDataYear.getMonth() == 11) { // When .getmonth() == 11, this shows two years overlapping with each other, making the label look ugly
  const firstDataYearOffset = d3.timeDay.offset(firstDataYear, 1);
  var tickValues = x.ticks().filter(function(d) {
    return !d.getMonth()
  });
  if (tickValues.length && firstDataYearOffset.getFullYear() !== tickValues[1].getFullYear()) {
    tickValues = [firstDataYearOffset].concat(tickValues);
  } else {
    tickValues = [firstDataYearOffset];
  }
} else {
  var tickValues = x.ticks().filter(function(d) {
    return !d.getMonth()
  });
  if (tickValues.length && firstDataYear.getFullYear() !== tickValues[0].getFullYear()) {
    tickValues = [firstDataYear].concat(tickValues);
  } else {
    tickValues = [firstDataYear];
  }
}

xYearAxis.tickValues(tickValues);

var yearAxis = g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "yearaxis axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + 25) + ")")
  .call(xYearAxis);

var valueAxis = g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis grid")
  .call(yAxis);

monthAxis.selectAll("g").select("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + barWidth / 2 + ",0)");

var options = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
  return key !== "date";
}).reverse();
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(options.slice().filter(function(type) {
    return type != "total"
  }))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
  });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .attr('class', function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .style("fill", z)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    if (d == 'col_2') {
      d3.selectAll(".col_2").style("fill", '#008394');
    }
    if (d == 'col_1') {
      d3.selectAll(".col_1").style("fill", '#80061b');
    };

  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    d3.selectAll(".col_2").style("fill", col_2_col);
    d3.selectAll(".col_1").style("fill", col_1_col);
  });

function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width - 24)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d) {
    return capitalizeFirstLetter(d.replace("col_1", "Column 1").replace("col_2", "Column 2"));
  })
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    if (d == 'col_2') {
      d3.selectAll(".col_2").style("fill", '#008394');
    }
    if (d == 'col_1') {
      d3.selectAll(".col_1").style("fill", '#80061b');
    };

  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    d3.selectAll(".col_2").style("fill", col_2_col);
    d3.selectAll(".col_1").style("fill", col_1_col);
  });;

// Initialize jQuery slider
$('div#month-slider').slider({
  min: 1,
  max: 25,
  value: defaultSliderValue,
  create: function() {
    // add value to the handle on slider creation
    $(this).find('.ui-slider-handle').html($(this).slider("value"));
  },
  slide: function(e, ui) {
    // change values on slider handle and label based on slider value 
    $(e.target).find('.ui-slider-handle').html(ui.value);

    // calculate offset date based on slider value
    var offsetDate = ui.value ? d3.timeDay.offset(d3.timeMonth.offset((new Date(datePlusOneMonth.getFullYear(), datePlusOneMonth.getMonth() - ui.value)), 1), -1) : min
    // set x domain and re-render xAxis
    x.domain([offsetDate, datePlusOneMonth]);
    g.select('.x.axis').call(xMonthAxis);

    const firstDataYear = x.domain()[0];
    if (firstDataYear.getMonth() == 11) { // When .getmonth() == 11, this shows two years overlapping with each other, making the label look ugly
      const firstDataYearOffset = d3.timeDay.offset(firstDataYear, 1);
      var tickValues = x.ticks().filter(function(d) {
        return !d.getMonth()
      });
      if (tickValues.length == 2 && firstDataYearOffset.getFullYear() !== tickValues[1].getFullYear()) {
        tickValues = [firstDataYearOffset].concat(tickValues);
      } else {
        tickValues = [firstDataYearOffset];
      }
    } else {
      var tickValues = x.ticks().filter(function(d) {
        return !d.getMonth()
      });
      if (tickValues.length && firstDataYear.getFullYear() !== tickValues[0].getFullYear()) {
        tickValues = [firstDataYear].concat(tickValues);
      } else {
        tickValues = [firstDataYear];
      }
    }
    xYearAxis.tickValues(tickValues);
    g.select('.yearaxis.axis').call(xYearAxis);


    // calculate filtered data based on new offset date, set y axis domain and re-render y axis
    var filteredData = data.filter(function(d) {
      return d.date >= offsetDate;
    });
    y.domain([0, d3.max(filteredData, function(d) {
      return d.total;
    })]).nice();
    g.select('.y.axis').transition().duration(200).call(yAxis);


    // re-render the bars based on new filtered data
    // the bars 
    var bars = g.select("g.bars")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(filteredData));

    var barRects = bars.enter().append("g").merge(bars)
      .attr('class', function(d) {
        return d.key;
      })
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return z(d.key);
      })
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      });

    barRects.exit().remove();

    barRects.enter()
      .append("rect");

    barWidth = (width - margin.right - margin.left) / (filteredData.length + barPad);

    monthAxis.selectAll("g").select("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + barWidth / 2 + ",0)");

    g.select("g.bars").selectAll('g rect')
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.data.date);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d[1]);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]);
      })
      .attr("width", barWidth)
      .on("mousemove", function(d) {

        //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
        var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.mouse(this)[0]) + 88;
        var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.mouse(this)[1]) + 50;
        var value = d.data[d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('class')]; // differentiating between col1 and col2 values
        var totalCount = d.data["total"];
        var valuePercent = value / totalCount;
        var valueClass = d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('class').replace("col_1", "Column 1").replace("col_2", "Column 2");

        //Update the tooltip position and value
        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .style("left", xPosition + "px")
          .style("top", yPosition + "px")

        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .select("#count")
          .text(formatNum(value)); // return the value 

        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .select("#totalCount")
          .text(formatNum(totalCount)); // return the value 

        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .select("#percent")
          .text((valuePercent * 100).toFixed(1) + "%"); // return the value 

        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .select("#month")
          .text(d3.timeFormat("%B %Y")(d.data.date)); // return the value 

        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .select("#sessionLabel")
          .text(valueClass); // return the class 

        //Show the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);

      })
      .on("mouseout", function() {
        //Hide the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
      });

  }
});

g.append("text")
  .attr("class", "title")
  .attr("x", (width / 2))
  .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Title");
```

```css
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 290px;
  z-index: 2;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.legend {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 60%;
}

#tooltip.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#tooltip p {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

g[class="col_1"] rect:hover {
  fill: #80061b;
}

g[class="col_2"] rect:hover {
  fill: #008394;
}

div.slider-container {
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 80px;
}

div#month-slider {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 330px;
  background: #e3eff4;
}

div#month-slider .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  width: 25%;
}

div#month-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.grid line {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  stroke-opacity: 0.7;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid path {
  stroke-width: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/1.7.0/d3-legend.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
    <p><strong>Month: </strong><span id="month"></span>
      <p>
        <p><strong><span id="sessionLabel"></span>: </strong><span id="count"></span> (<span id="percent"></span>)</p>
        <p><strong>Total: </strong><span id="totalCount"></span></p>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-container" style='inline-block;'>
    <span style='margin-left:6em;display:inline-block;position:relative;top:15px;'><strong>Number of Months Displayed:</strong></span>
    <div id="month-slider" style='inline-block;'></div>
  </div>
```

I've seen https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6452972, but most of it is gibberish to me. In particular, I get lost as soon as I get to the `track-inset` and `track-overlay` class assignments - I don't understand what the purposes of these are.

I also started by commenting out the jQuery slider and inserting the code

```
var slider = g.append("g")
              .attr("id", "month-slider")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left + width/2) + ",0)");
```

above the `monthAxis` variable declaration, but beyond this - i.e., the bar filtering based on the value of the slider, as well as the label attached to the slider - I'm lost on how to do. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about https://bl.ocks.org/Lulkafe/3832d628340038d9484fbd9edb705e01 ? I think that should be easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for a solution, you can use the d3 Step Slider I wrote. (*and I've added a few comments as well*)

Here it is: https://bl.ocks.org/shashank2104/d7051d80e43098bf9a48e9b6d3e10e73

And in the `dragged` callback (i.e. where you receive the drag value), use the value to call the `slide` function of the jQuery slider. I think you should be able to replace jQuery with d3 easily with this. I was gonna do it for you but I think it's better for you to give it a shot and get back to me if you face any issues. I'll definitely help you out as I know the data/chart details in your case.